# Set the content mid-page with CSS3

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="width: 100%; position:fixed; display: block;" class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="width: 100%; height: 30px; ">mid</div>
</div>
```

I am going to set the div with the 'child' class in the mid-page using css.
The parent div's position will be fixed. 
how do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position an element centered in the screen:

```
/* Staple class for V and H centered element */
.vertical-and-horizontally-centered-element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* support for cross browser compatibility */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

To center the text within in the center of the element use `text-align: center`. After we put together all your code, you get the following result:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}

.child {
  height: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* support for cross browser compatibility */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">mid</div>
</div>
```

Another comment, move your inline CSS to its own CSS file, unless you must keep it inline for specific reasons... my two cents :-)

Let me know if you have any questions in the comments below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is everthing centered: https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/5/

```
.parent{background-color: lightblue;}
.child{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 50%;

  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```